# "There is no A or B" vs "There is no A and B"

Tags: negation

If A doesn't exist and B doesn't exist either, what is the correct form below?

> There is no A and B.

or

> There is no A or B.

What if the sentence is long, such as

> There is no bound on message delay or relative process speed.

Would this construction be correct?

Comment: There is neither A nor B.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the sentence is long, such as "There is no bound on message delay or relative process speed." Would this construction be correct? I think "There is neither bound on message delay nor on relative process speed" would be odd...

Comment: "There is neither bound on message delay nor on relative process speed" would be odd because it's not English. "There is neither a bound on message delay nor on relative process speed", on the other hand, is grammatical, idiomatic, and ubiquitous.

Comment: Ubiquitous, are you certain? :-)

Comment: @RegDwigнt that's a bit much to say the phrase is *not English* because the "**no** bound" was used. I would, however, venture to say that even with "a bound", I don't fully grasp its meaning. What does "bound" mean, Eduardo Bezerra?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, we think of *A and B* as a single word, in which case keep the *and*:

> There's no fish 'n' chips.

Otherwise, you can use *or*:

> We have no cats or dogs.

You can also use *neither ... nor ...*. This is very clear, and is strongly preferred in formal speech or writing:

> I can offer you neither hope nor succour.

In some dialects, you can drop the *neither*:

> If it's use nor ornament, chuck it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **either/or** might fit your particular requirements.

> There is no bound on message delay or relative process speed.
>
> There is no bound on *either* message delay *or* relative process speed.

It's technically neither/nor, but sounds better and apt for your example.