# Do "No A or B" and "No A and B" mean the same thing?

Tags: differences, present-participles

Hopefully my question is not the same as [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140981/there-is-no-a-or-b-vs-there-is-no-a-and-b) as I am asking about the English in writing a prohibition. Do "No A or B" and "No A and B" mean the same thing, where A and B are present participle of some verb?

For example: Is there any difference between

> No eating and drinking

and

> No eating or drinking

?

Which one of these two, if any, should one say if he/she wishes to express the idea "either A or B is allowed", but not both A and B (such as drinking alcohol and driving)?

Comment: People usually make the mistake of glossing over whether they're giving the precisionist / logical or the pragmatically-informed answer here, and answer as if there's only one way to handle this. Since this is ELU (how most Anglophones actually _use_ English), I'll just give the pragmatically-driven answer. One should say "Either A or B is allowed, but not **both** A and B." / Note that 'Don't drink and drive' has a default meaning by usage, whereas 'No eating and drinking' would probably be taken to be equivalent to 'No eating or drinking'.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers.  Are you writing the sign, or are you seeing that sign?

**If you are writing the sign**  then write

> No eating or drinking

or

> No eating
>   No drinking

**If you see the sign**  "No eating and drinking"  then assume it means

> No eating
>   No drinking

You should not assume that you can get out of trouble by saying "I was only eating, not drinking, and ELU.SE says that sign means I can do one or the other but not both".

Answer (score 1):

## No, they do not mean generally the same thing.

"No A or B" would generally mean "Do not do A, and also do not do B." For instance, a sign saying "No eating or drinking" would mean that both the consumption of food and the drinking of beverages are banned.

"No A and B" would mean "Do not do both A and B simultaneously." For instance, a sign might say "No running and jumping", which would mean "do not jump while running."

Comment: Indeed, *don't eat and smoke* is different from *don't eat or smoke*.